# Adding Date string to beginning of filename in C, WINAPI

Tags: c, windows, api, date, filenames

I'm trying to add a date string to the beginning of my filename and I can't see why this isn't working. I have a function which grabs the date and time and turns it into a string format, then I have a GetSaveFileName window so the user can save the file in the window box. when I run the program, it crashes when the file is saved. Can anyone see what mistake I've made?

Thanks in advance

```
// Set file name
void Set_FileName(HWND hWnd)
{
// This is the structure that creates the windows open/save dialogue system
OPENFILENAME ofn;

// This is the path and filename that the user will select/write
char file_name[100];

// Initial address set to zero?
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(OPENFILENAME));

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hwndOwner = hWnd;
// This is the parameter of the file name and location
ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
// Set the initial file name
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = 100;
// What file types the user can use
ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;

// Needs a particular linker library to work, libcomdlg32.a
GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

// Update what the current date and time is
Get_Date();

// Add a string to the start of the filename
sprintf(file_name, "%s" + (LPARAM)ofn.lpstrFile, s_Date);
// Update filename
ofn.lpstrFile = file_name;
}
```

This is the date function. There isn't any error here, it's just for reference. It updates a global string called s_Date;

```
// Function to record the date and time as a string
void Get_Date()
{
// Grab the current time
time_t now = time(0);

// I have no idea what is happening here
tm *ltm = localtime(&now);

// Turn the date into a readable string format
stringstream ss_Date;

ss_Date << 1900 + ltm->tm_year << 1 + ltm->tm_mday << "_" << ltm->tm_hour << ltm->tm_min << "_" << endl;
ss_Date >> s_Date;
}
```

Comment: `"%s" + (LPARAM)ofn.lpstrFile` seems wrong (adding two pointers seldom does what one thinks). Do you perhaps want `"%s%s", ofn.lpstrFile, s_Date`? And the `Get_Date` snippet is C++ code, not C.

Comment: `tm *ltm = localtime(&now);` is not C either, it would be `struct tm *ltm = localtime(&now);`

Comment: `ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files\0*.TXT\0";` makes `ofn.lpstrFilter` a pointer to a *read-only* string. Any attempt to change it (inside `GetSaveFileName(&ofn);`) invokes UB.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
sprintf(file_name, "%s" + (LPARAM)ofn.lpstrFile, s_Date);
```

note that `ofn.lpstrFile` already points to `file_name` so you are overwriting it. In this case you need a separate (new) buffer to construct the filename.

Also, `"%s" + (LPARAM)ofn.lpstrFile` is not a valid string expression. Use `"%s%s",...`

(and see the other comments for more suggestions and errors)